# same name but with different case variable and function names in c

Tags: c, microcontroller, keil

I have a variable named setlocal and a function named void SetLocal(void)

I am using C51 keil compiler to build the code and the linker gives following error:

"EXTERNAL ATTRIBUT DO NOT MATCH PUBLIC"

Is it not possible to use same name for function and a variable? with different case?

Comment: It may be a deficiency in the compiler. But a compiler that isn't case sensitive must be paleolithic. As far as the language is concerned, `foo`, `foO`, `fOo`, `Foo` are four different names. Or you have a mistake in your code that you overlooked.

Comment: Does the compiler really shout in upper-case with misspellings?  Could your `setlocal` variable be running foul of the standard C function `setlocale()` because the compiler is truncating to 8 significant characters?  If the environment only supports 8 significant characters, it is not C99 compliant, but it's possible that support for small systems does not include the longer names mandated by C99 (compared with C89, which only demanded 6 characters mono-case for external names).

Comment: No In my case, it does not give error with misspellings. its C51 compiler may be not fully c99 compliant. I have changed variable name to setlocal1 to solve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

That particular compiler is for embedded systems (using the 8051 chips) and is really targeted for those environments. I've seen compilers in that arena that don't even support floating point, and Keil make it clear that, while it's *based* on C90, there are [deviations](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/c51/c51_xa.htm) from that standard.

As per the compiler limitations listed on the [Keil website](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/c51/c51_xd.htm):

> Names may be up to 255 characters long. The C language provides for case sensitivity in regard to function and variable names. However, **for compatibility reasons, all names in the object file appear in capital letters.** It is therefore irrelevant if an external object name within the source program is written in capital or small letters.

So it's a safe bet that, as far as the linker is concerned, you have a conflict between the `setlocal` variable and the `SetLocal` function, both of which would be seen as `SETLOCAL`.

That also explains (as stated in one on your comments) why changing the variable name to `setlocal1` fixes your problem. While the symbols are not case sensitive, they *are* unique to 255 characters.